# Recyclerview with sticky header and subheader

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to create recyclerView adapter with sticky header and subheaders ([recyclerview structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBoog.png))? 
At the beginning I did like in this [example](https://github.com/mightyfrog/FlexibleAdapter-Header-Section-Sample), made using FlexibleAdapter. In the example there is sticky header only.

```
data class SectionItem(private val title: String, private val headerItem: HeaderItem) :
        AbstractFlexibleItem(),
        ISectionable {
```

`override fun getLayoutRes(): Int = R.layout.section

override fun getHeader(): HeaderItem = headerItem

override fun setHeader(headerItem: HeaderItem) {
}

override fun createViewHolder(view: View?, adapter: FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>>?): ViewHolder = ViewHolder(view, adapter)

override fun bindViewHolder(adapter: FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>>?, holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>?) {
    holder?.let {
        it.title.text = title
    }
}

class ViewHolder(view: View?, adapter: FlexibleAdapter<*>?) : FlexibleViewHolder(view, adapter) {
    var title: TextView = view?.findViewById(R.id.title)!!
}}`

In SectionItem I can't implement ISectionable with subHeader.
Having looked at the documentation for the FlexibleAdapter library, I thought that it was impossible to create a list structure with a sub header. Tell please what other way make a sub header that would match [recyclerview structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBoog.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your model has some kind of data about date. If i'm geussing right you have to create 3 different ViewHolders:

1. ViewHolder for StickyHeader
2. ViewHolder for SubHeader
3. ViewHolder for your json item

Now create method which will accept `List<YourJsonObject>` list. Inside that method You will have to iterate through that list and check date of Your model. In there, you should set some logic which will check previous `YourJsonObject` date.

```
val newList = mutableListOf<SomeKindOfInterface>()

fun setData(list: List<YourJsonObject>) {
    newList.clear()

    var previousMonth = 0
    var previousDay = 0
    for (yourJsonObject in list) {

        if (yourJsonObject.month != previousMonth) {
            previousMonth = yourJsonObject.month
            newList.add(MonthObject(yourJsonObject.month))
        }

        if (yourJsonObject.day != previousDay) {
            previousDay = yourJsonObject.day
            newList.add(DayObject(yourJsonObject.day))
        }

        newList.add(yourJsonObject)
    }
}



class YourJsonObject(
    val month: Int,
    val day: Int
) : SomeKindOfInterface

class MonthObject(val month: Int) : SomeKindOfInterface

class DayObject(val day: Int) : SomeKindOfInterface

interface SomeKindOfInterface
```

After that you should override `getItemViewType(position: Int)` and `onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)`. In there based on item position of `newList` return different ViewType depending on you data.

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return when (newList.get(position)) {
        is YourJsonObject -> 0
        is MonthObject -> 1
        is DayObject -> 2
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        0 -> createYourJsonObjectViewHolder
        1 -> createMonthObjectViewHolder
        2 -> createDayObjectViewHolder
    }
}
```

Of course code which I gave You here is only example but with this information you should be able adopt it to you problem.

`MonthObject` is yout StickyHeader and `DayObject` is your SubHeader.

Comment: This is great of course. Parsing an json-object is not a problem, but how to put the data (map data) to sticky header and subheader - that's exactly what's not working.

Comment: Ok, I made two levels of headers, it remains to fix one of them - to do it sticky

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help You. You can up vote my answer if you want to help other ppl in future :)